# Overlapping labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have the following plot:

There are two overlaping labels and I do not know how to do to show both of them without one being on top of the other one. My code is:

```
ggplot(data = tic,
       aes(x = tic,
           y = Promedio,
           fill = rural)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = tipo),
             size = 2,
             alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Departamental" = 22,
                                "Distrital" = 21,
                                "Municipal" = 23),
                     name = "Tipo de SE") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0.19,0.83),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill=rgb(1,1,1), 
                                     size=0.5, 
                                     linetype="solid"),
    legend.box = "horizontal",
    legend.title = element_text(size=13 )
  ) + geom_hline(yintercept = 250,
                 linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 91,
             linetype = "dashed") +
  ylab("Promedio del puntaje global del Examen Saber 11° 2016-2019") +
  xlab("Porcentaje de establecimientos educativos con TIC") +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Ruralidad",
                      low = "green",
                      high = "red") +
  geom_label(data = tic[tic$etc=="CALDAS",],
             aes(y = Promedio,
                 label = "Caldas",
                 fontface = "bold"),
             size = 3) +
  geom_label(data = tic[tic$etc=="RISARALDA",],
             aes(y = Promedio,
                 label = "Risaralda",
                 fontface = "bold"),
             size = 3) +
  geom_label(data = tic[tic$etc=="PEREIRA",],
             aes(y = Promedio,
                 label = "Pereira"),
             size = 3,
             fontface = "bold") +
  geom_label(data = tic[tic$etc=="ARMENIA",],
             aes(y = Promedio,
                 label = "Armenia"),
             size = 3,
             fontface = "bold") +
  geom_label(data = tic[tic$etc=="QUINDÍO",],
             aes(y = Promedio,
                 label = "Quindío"),
             size = 3,
             fontface = "bold") +
  labs(caption = "Nota: Las líneas punteadas corresponden a las medianas de las correspondientes variables")
```

I tried by giving them some angle using the `angle` argument in `geom_label()` but it did not work. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

My data can me reproducible by:

```
structure(list(etc = c("AMAZONAS", "ANTIOQUIA", "APARTADÓ", "ARAUCA", 
"ARMENIA", "ATLÁNTICO", "BARRANCABERMEJA", "BARRANQUILLA", "BELLO", 
"BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOLÍVAR", "BOYACÁ", "BUCARAMANGA", "BUENAVENTURA", 
"BUGA", "CALDAS", "CALI", "CAQUETÁ", "CARTAGENA", "CARTAGO", 
"CASANARE", "CAUCA", "CESAR", "CHÍA", "CHOCÓ", "CIÉNAGA", "CÓRDOBA", 
"CÚCUTA", "CUNDINAMARCA", "DOSQUEBRADAS", "DUITAMA", "ENVIGADO", 
"FACATATIVÁ", "FLORENCIA", "FLORIDABLANCA", "FUSAGASUGÁ", "GIRARDOT", 
"GIRÓN", "GUAINÍA", "GUAVIARE", "HUILA", "IBAGUÉ", "IPIALES", 
"ITAGÜÍ", "JAMUNDÍ", "LA GUAJIRA", "LORICA", "MAGANGUÉ", "MAGDALENA", 
"MAICAO", "MALAMBO", "MANIZALES", "MEDELLÍN", "META", "MONTERÍA", 
"MOSQUERA", "NARIÑO", "NEIVA", "NORTE DE SANTANDER", "PALMIRA", 
"PASTO", "PEREIRA", "PIEDECUESTA", "PITALITO", "POPAYÁN", "PUTUMAYO", 
"QUIBDÓ", "QUINDÍO", "RIOHACHA", "RIONEGRO", "RISARALDA", "SABANETA", 
"SAHAGÚN", "SAN ANDRÉS", "SANTA MARTA", "SANTANDER", "SINCELEJO", 
"SOACHA", "SOGAMOSO", "SOLEDAD", "SUCRE", "TOLIMA", "TULUÁ", 
"TUMACO", "TUNJA", "TURBO", "URIBIA", "VALLE DEL CAUCA", "VALLEDUPAR", 
"VAUPÉS", "VICHADA", "VILLAVICENCIO", "YOPAL", "YUMBO", "ZIPAQUIRÁ"
), tic = c(77.5, 77.4579783559751, 63.013698630137, 81.335952848723, 
96.3302752293578, 96.113074204947, 91.0994764397906, 95.0909090909091, 
89.5161290322581, 96.3756177924217, 81.0593900481541, 92.1052631578947, 
97.2602739726027, 82.1727019498607, 91.2280701754386, 90.8333333333333, 
92.0477137176938, 78.7625418060201, 94.2184154175589, 95.7142857142857, 
92.3076923076923, 83.2853025936599, 77.3056057866184, 92.9292929292929, 
33.5483870967742, 72.4550898203593, 79.8767967145791, 96.037296037296, 
92.0209059233449, 88.8111888111888, 85.1851851851852, 90.6976744186046, 
94.5054945054945, 77.5510204081633, 97.5609756097561, 94.1747572815534, 
93.9024390243902, 93.75, 77.3584905660377, 76.056338028169, 95.1333333333333, 
94.7780678851175, 90.8256880733945, 94.1860465116279, 90.3508771929825, 
35.0553505535055, 91.6129032258064, 89.5238095238095, 74.7357293868922, 
48.8584474885845, 92.7536231884058, 95.7345971563981, 95.4486345903771, 
76.2303664921466, 81.8452380952381, 98.2142857142857, 77.3294908741595, 
92.5675675675676, 85.6265984654732, 94.2222222222222, 95.1807228915663, 
93.4169278996865, 89.5161290322581, 98.9417989417989, 93.5622317596567, 
69.1897654584222, 57.5, 98.2517482517483, 66.6666666666667, 96.6101694915254, 
85.546218487395, 96.6666666666667, 96.4912280701754, 91.1764705882353, 
91.1357340720222, 92.2948771345273, 95.2380952380952, 97.4137931034483, 
97.2222222222222, 93.8848920863309, 86.0730593607306, 92.0260782347041, 
98.0769230769231, 62.1794871794872, 93.2926829268293, 70, 5.58766859344894, 
95.1026856240126, 88.821752265861, 22.9357798165138, 68.4466019417476, 
91.2181303116147, 80, 95.7746478873239, 95.8333333333333), tipo = c("Departamental", 
"Departamental", "Municipal", "Departamental", "Municipal", "Departamental", 
"Municipal", "Distrital", "Municipal", "Distrital", "Departamental", 
"Departamental", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Departamental", 
"Municipal", "Departamental", "Distrital", "Municipal", "Departamental", 
"Departamental", "Departamental", "Municipal", "Departamental", 
"Municipal", "Departamental", "Municipal", "Departamental", "Municipal", 
"Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", 
"Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Departamental", "Departamental", 
"Departamental", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", 
"Departamental", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Departamental", "Municipal", 
"Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Departamental", "Municipal", 
"Municipal", "Departamental", "Municipal", "Departamental", "Municipal", 
"Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", 
"Departamental", "Municipal", "Departamental", "Municipal", "Municipal", 
"Departamental", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Departamental", "Distrital", 
"Departamental", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", 
"Departamental", "Departamental", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", 
"Municipal", "Municipal", "Departamental", "Municipal", "Departamental", 
"Departamental", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal", "Municipal"
), rural = c(87.9432624113475, 87.1920135938828, 61.25, 81.8032786885246, 
19.6428571428571, 27.0096463022508, 30.3030303030303, 0.489396411092985, 
6.66666666666667, 2.24803297115024, 77.2442588726514, 84.0325342465753, 
6.66666666666667, 20.4907975460123, 31.0077519379845, 82.9002514668902, 
6.15128844555278, 94.7916666666667, 8.81801125703565, 14.6666666666667, 
86.5912762520194, 89.4032134659526, 79.1833466773419, 50, 92.1666666666667, 
55.7471264367816, 82.4182603331277, 15.8013544018059, 78.5690950669716, 
19.4630872483221, 19.047619047619, 15.7303370786517, 16.3265306122449, 
59.2105263157895, 12.568306010929, 36.7924528301887, 6.59340659340659, 
36.2745098039216, 93.4065934065934, 89.7435897435898, 86.8037135278515, 
26.5402843601896, 57.6642335766423, 6.59340659340659, 54.0983606557377, 
81.2091503267974, 80.3680981595092, 40, 69.5017182130584, 73.7556561085973, 
8.69565217391304, 28.5714285714286, 7.63723150357995, 86.4527629233512, 
55.2325581395349, 6.45161290322581, 90.2942468159859, 26.4900662251656, 
85.9764705882353, 25.7462686567164, 37.5478927203065, 39.4886363636364, 
60.3053435114504, 72.4867724867725, 24.609375, 90.1760889712697, 
50.3311258278146, 74.6575342465753, 67.9054054054054, 52.4590163934426, 
84.7039473684211, 35.4838709677419, 78.6324786324786, 47.2222222222222, 
22.0379146919431, 88.7592376507196, 20, 3.62903225806452, 34.8623853211009, 
0.33112582781457, 74.5689655172414, 80.1830663615561, 44.7674418604651, 
84.1954022988506, 7.01754385964912, 86.4864864864865, 98.1515711645102, 
73.8644304682041, 32.5333333333333, 92.4242424242424, 91.8103448275862, 
18.1102362204724, 53.0864197530864, 40.5405405405405, 21), Promedio = c(225, 
248.75, 245.75, 260.25, 271.25, 234.75, 271.25, 261.75, 266.25, 
277, 225.75, 258.75, 290, 229.5, 265.5, 249.5, 256.25, 240, 250.25, 
260.25, 256.25, 229.25, 239.5, 288.75, 204.5, 224.5, 236.5, 271.5, 
264.75, 272.25, 292.5, 289, 276.5, 263.75, 291.75, 269.25, 252, 
269.25, 241.5, 240.25, 256.75, 271, 276.25, 271.25, 256.25, 229.5, 
232.75, 247.25, 221.5, 238.25, 243, 274.5, 269.5, 252.75, 266.75, 
284.5, 252.75, 278.25, 259.75, 277, 281.5, 270.5, 280.5, 281.75, 
266.25, 251.5, 226.75, 255, 248.25, 281, 248.75, 286.25, 259, 
246, 246.5, 264.75, 265.5, 261.5, 285.25, 253, 236.25, 240.25, 
263, 217.75, 289.75, 219.25, 207.5, 248.5, 259.75, 221, 235.5, 
271.75, 274, 248.25, 280.75)), row.names = c(NA, -95L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ggrepel::geom_label_repel`.  Note that the label placements are semi-random, so you many need to draw the plot a few times, or mess with `geom_label_repel` parameters to get something you like.

[image]

Change your `geom_label` calls like below

```
  geom_label(data = tic[tic$etc=="ARMENIA",],
             aes(y = Promedio,
                 label = "Armenia"),
             size = 3,
             fontface = "bold")
```

to `geom_label_repel` calls

```
  geom_label_repel(data = tic[tic$etc=="ARMENIA",],
             aes(y = Promedio,
                 label = "Armenia"),
             size = 3,
             fontface = "bold")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use `ggrepel`, it is better to have a single call to `geom_label_repel`. This means changing to a single `geom_label_repel` call like this:

```
geom_label_repel(data = tic[tic$etc %in% c("CALDAS","RISARALDA", "PEREIRA", 
                                           "ARMENIA", "QUINDÍO"),],
                 aes(y = Promedio, label = etc, fontface = "bold"),
                 size = 3)
```

This ensures that none of the groups are plotted on top of each other, and also makes your code shorter and more maintainable

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way to give the labels an angle?